# Работа с SSL telegram-bot-api

Tags: golang, telegram-bot

Пока писал бота пользовался сервисом ngrok, все работало, сейчас решил опубликовать на нашем сервере (веб сервер на IIS), настроил IIS в качестве прокси что бы запросы перенаправлял на localhost (настраивал через переопределение URL адресов), слал через браузер get запросы (для проверки) все работает, т.е. я вызываю внешний URL идет перенаправление на мой локальный. Однако бот не работал, стал гуглить понял что нужно использовать метод NewWebhookWithCert(), сгенерировал сертификат и закрытый ключ командой

openssl.exe req -new -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout webhook_pkey.key -out webhook_cert.pem -days 3650

в коде

```
bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert(net.WebhookURL, "webhook_cert.pem"))
```

еще

```
http.ListenAndServeTLS(":"+net.ListenPort, "webhook_cert.pem", "webhook_pkey.key", nil)
```

и ничего, фиг знает что еще делать, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас некорректный сертификат.

[В этом примере](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api) говорится что нужно сгенерировать сертификат указав `subject`.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 3560 -subj "//O=Org\CN=Test" -nodes
```

---

```
bot.SetWebhook(tgbotapi.NewWebhookWithCert(net.WebhookURL, "cert.pem"))
```

Или можете попробовать получить сертификат при помощи [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)